# How are GraphNode String IDs supposed to be used

Tags: godot, graph

Once you add several `GraphNode` instances to `GraphEdit` they get some unusual ID strings surrounded with `@` signs and with an attached ID. E.g. Running `get_connection_list()` returns following array:

```
[
  { 
    from: "StartNode",
    from_port: 0,
    to: "TransformNode",
    to_port: 0
  },
  {
    from: "TransformNode",
    from_port: 0,
    to: "@TransformNode@119",
    to_port: 0
  },
  {
    from: "@TransformNode@119",
    from_port: 0,
    to: "@TransformNode@120",
    to_port: 0
  },
  {
    from: "@TransformNode@120",
    from_port: 0,
    to: "OutputNode",
    to_port: 0
  }
]
```

How can I reference / work with those IDs and e.g. retrieve the corresponding node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are `Node` names. You should be able to retrieve the `Node`s with `get_node` (or `get_node_or_null` or `get_node_and_resource`), just like any other `Node`.

---

Godot will not allow two `Node`s with the same `NodePath`. So, when you add a `Node` with the same `name` as a sibling `Node`, Godot will generate a new `name` for it. **This is NOT particular of `GraphEdit` or `GraphNode`.** *Godot will check for collisions and generate names for any kind of `Node`.*

---

In this case, you seem to have been adding `Node`s with the `name` set to `"TransformNode"`. The first one you added has no problem, since the `name` was not used before by any sibling `Node`. However, when adding the second sibling `Node` with the `name` set to `"TransformNode"` it conflicts with the one you already added. So Godot generates a new `name` of the format `@name@number` (for example `"@TransformNode@119"`). And it continues doing that for any other sibling `Node` with the same `name` added.

---

I should also mention that Godot does the same thing if you add anonymous `Node`s. I mean `Node`s with empty string for `name`. So you get nodes with names like `"@@20"` (notice this follows the same rule as above, the name part just happens to be an empty string). *Adding anonymous `Node`s also avoids checking for name collision. Which can be a performance improvement if you are adding a lot of `Node`s in a short period of time (there are other better optimizations for bullet hell games, by the way, but that is a different topic).*

---

The numbers are just counting up, among `name` collisions and anonymous `Node`s. However, a `GraphEdit` creates a lot of anonymous `Control`s for its visual representation, which make the count go up relatively fast. As a result the numbers can be hard to predict, but should be consistent.

Comment: Thanks! Why does the connection list use Strings for reference anyways and not a reference pointer to the object? Seems really amateurish…

Comment: @adius It makes it easy to parse a serialized form: you read that node `"a"` is connected to node `"b"`, but `GraphEdit` wants references not names, so we first need to retrieve the nodes by name or keep them in a dictionary, so we made the code more complex. Letting `GraphEdit` handle it makes it easier to use. And usability is important in Godot. Plus, you are getting an snapshot, editing the graph does not affect it. Also, if you need to process the graph to generate some output you can take advantage of node names. In fact, Godot does this for the visual shader language code generation.